# Systemctl dependency failure, stop dependent services

Tags: linux, service, systemd, watchdog, systemctl

I have 2 services a.service and b.service. 
a.service is shown

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/admin/run.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target,
```

b.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/sh $HOME/theFolder/run.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, when i start b.service, i'm sure a.service will be started.
During runtime, suddenly someone messes with /home/admin/run.sh and systemd is unable to start a.service (also systemctl status a.service shows failed as status). Now is there a option so that b.service can know that a.service is failed and it should stop/exit?

Comment: BindsTo=a.service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add either `BindsTo=` or `Requires=` to your `[Unit]` section, as documented in `man systemd.unit`:

> **Requires=**
>        Configures requirement dependencies on other units. If this unit gets activated, the units listed here
>        will be activated as well. If one of the other units gets deactivated or its activation fails, this unit
>        will be deactivated. This option may be specified more than once or multiple space-separated units may
>        be specified in one option in which case requirement dependencies for all listed names will be created.
>        Note that requirement dependencies do not influence the order in which services are started or stopped.
>        This has to be configured independently with the After= or Before= options. If a unit foo.service
>        requires a unit bar.service as configured with Requires= and no ordering is configured with After= or
>        Before=, then both units will be started simultaneously and without any delay between them if
>        foo.service is activated. Often, it is a better choice to use Wants= instead of Requires= in order to
>        achieve a system that is more robust when dealing with failing services.
>
> **BindsTo=**
>        Configures requirement dependencies, very similar in style to Requires=, however in addition to this
>        behavior, it also declares that this unit is stopped when any of the units listed suddenly disappears.
>        Units can suddenly, unexpectedly disappear if a service terminates on its own choice, a device is
>        unplugged or a mount point unmounted without involvement of systemd.