# systemd: Stop dependent service when main service crashes

Tags: linux, service, systemd, systemctl

*(systemd version 229)*

I have a primary service A, and a secondary service B.  The primary A can run by itself.  But service B cannot run correctly by itself: it needs A to be running (technically B *can* run, but this is what I want `systemd` to prevent).  My goal: **If A is not running, B should not run**.  Given that A and B are running, when A stops or dies/crashes, then B should be stopped.

How do I achieve this?

I get close by adding [Unit] items to b.service, using

```
Requisite=A.service
After=A.service
```

The result of the above is that

- B won't start unless A is running (good).
- B is stopped when A is stopped (good).
- However, if I kill A, service B continues to run (bad).

How can I fix this last behavior?  Neither `PartOf` nor `BindsTo` seems to do the trick, but perhaps I don't have the right incantation of combinations of options?  Its not clear to me from the man pages what options can be combined.

systemd.unit man page: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html
Related: [Systemctl dependency failure, stop dependent services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714731/systemctl-dependency-failure-stop-dependent-services)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Really? Lots of systemd questions have already been answered here in SO. And its related to the development of systems, not only apps are developed.

Comment: Instead of the Requisite, have you tried using BindsTo as in the linked question is proposed as solution?

Comment: Thanx, I'll move the question to S/E.   @Jesus, BindsTo handles the kill B part, but it has the side-effect that when I start B, A is also started.  I want B to give a dependency error as it does with Requisite.  But I guess BindsTo is the better option of the two.  Thanx for suggestion that I look at it again.

Comment: Moved to ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/884211/systemd-service-dependency-if-a-is-not-running-b-should-not-run

Answer (score 2):

You can use, `Requires=` or `PartOf=` or `BindTo=`

see [this article](https://pychao.com/2021/02/24/difference-between-partof-and-bindsto-in-a-systemd-unit/#:%7E:text=PartOf%3D%20Configures%20dependencies%20similar%20to%20Requires%3D%2C%20but%20limited,here%2C%20the%20action%20is%20propagated%20to%20this%20unit.) for detail of their usage

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your 3rd objective make use of `PartOf` keyword.

In B.service you need to add dependency on A under `[Unit]` section as below

```
[Unit]
..
..
PartOf=A.service
```

With this, whenever A is killed B shall also stop.

Comment: Thanx @DarkKnight, but PartOf doesn't quite do it; if I stop A normally then B is stopped (good), but if A dies or is killed, B continues to run (bad).  Using BindsTo seems closer, but it has a different issue.  Anyway, fwiw, I've move this question to ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

If you start Service A with `Type=notify` you may be able to achieve something if you terminate A with `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`, you can actually handle that and send a message on `$NOTIFY_FD` to `systemd`, but that option is still not possible with `SIGKILL`. It's a bit involved but might be able to achieve what you want.

You should also consider making A `Restart=always`. This will at-least make sure that A will remain available and B won't keep giving out errors. When you `kill` A (outside `systemd`), there's no way for `systemd` to know that A was killed - especially if you do so with `kill -9` (`SIGKILL` cannot be handled). . So one of the best way to handle that will be to make Service A, `Restart=always`.